# Hessian of the Dirichlet energy

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a unit ball and $\mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the unit sphere. For any $u \in H^1(B_1;\mathbb{S}^2)$, we consider the Dirichlet energy:
$$E[u] = \int_{B_1} |\nabla u|^2.$$
I want to find the Hessian of $E$ in some directions. Suppose $f$ and $g$ is in the space $H^1_0(B_1;\mathbb{R}^3)$. Is the Hessian given by
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dtds}\int_{B_1} \left|\nabla \dfrac{u+tf+sg}{|u+tf+sg|}\right|^2?$$
Also, may I have the expected answer or some reference for this problem? Thank you so much for your help!